# Want to add horizontal line only for last row in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't want horizontal and vertical lines for the `DataGrid`, so I used `GridLinesVisibility="None"`.

I want a horizontal border for the last row.

I tried with Following code, please let me know what i did wrong here,
Lastraw is property having last Row's RowIndex.

```xml
<CommonWPF:HLabDataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LastRow}" Value="Bottom">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Thickness Left="0" Right="0" Top="0" Bottom="1"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</CommonWPF:HLabDataGrid.RowStyle>
```

**DataGrid** The Way I want:
[image: DataGrid The Way I want]

Comment: What exactly is lastrow?  I would have expected a boolean and a comparison to value True.

Comment: That maybe not be your question but if you just want to add a border on the end, you may look to put your datagrid inside a GroupBox to do the trick. That is a very different way to think the problem hope it can help you

Comment: @XimazeC i want border for last row not for the grid , plz look attached image.

Comment: Ok then my bad, didn't see the attached image. Hope you'll find the answer.